# Handing over std::vector to function with pointer

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have been searching on Google an in this forum for a while, but I could not find any answer or tip for my problem. Tutorials couldn't help me either...

I want to redistribute some points, stored in a vector p_org. (x-value is stored as double).
Therefore I have the function distribute, which is defined in maths.h

```
distribute_tanh(&p_org_temp,&p_new_temp,iz,spacing[0],spacing[1],l_rot[(kk+1)*iz-2],status);
```

The function distribute_tanh does look like this:

```
inline void distribute_tanh (std::vector<double> *p_org, std::vector<double> *p_new, const int n_points, double spacing_begin, double spacing_end, const double total_length, double status){

        //if status == 0: FLAP, if status == 1: SLAT
        std::cout << "spacing_begin: " << spacing_begin << " spacing_end: " << spacing_end << std::endl;

        double s_begin = spacing_begin / total_length;
        double s_end = spacing_end / total_length;
        double A = sqrt(s_end/s_begin);
        double B = 1 / (sqrt(s_end*s_begin)*n_points);

        std::cout << "A: " << A << " B: " << B << std::endl;

        std::vector<double> u (n_points);
        std::vector<double> sn (n_points);
        double dx;
        double dy;

        std::cout << "Control at the beginning: p_org: " << (p_org) << " p_new: " << (p_new) << " n_points: " << n_points << " s_begin: " << s_begin << " s_end: " << s_end << " total_length: " << total_length << std::endl;
```

//problem no. 1

```
        for (int i=0;i<n_points;i++){
                if (B > 1.001) {
                        if (B < 2.7829681) {
                            double Bq=B-1;
                            dy=sqrt(6*Bq)*(1-0.15*Bq+0.057321429*pow(Bq,2)-0.024907295*pow(Bq,3)+0.0077424461*pow(Bq,4)-0.0010794123*pow(Bq,5));
                        } else if (B > 2.7829681) {
                            double Bv=log(B);
                            double Bw=1/B-0.028527431;
                            dy=Bv+(1+1/Bv)*log(2*Bv)-0.02041793+0.24902722*Bw+1.9496443*pow(Bw,2)-2.6294547*pow(Bw,3)+8.56795911*pow(Bw,4);
                }
                        u[i]=0.5+(tanh(dy*(i*(1.0/n_points)-0.5))/(2*tanh(dy/2)));

                } 

            else if (B < 0.999) {
                        if (B <  0.26938972) {
                            dx=M_PI*(1-B+pow(B,2)-(1+(pow(M_PI,2))/6)*pow(B,3)+6.794732*pow(B,4)-13.205501*pow(B,5)+11.726095*pow(B,6));
                    } else if (B > 0.26938972) {
                            double Bq=1-B;
                            dx=sqrt(6*Bq)*(1+0.15*Bq+0.057321429*pow(Bq,2)+0.048774238*pow(Bq,3)-0.053337753*pow(Bq,4)+0.075845134*pow(Bq,5));
                }           
                u[i]=0.5+(tan(dx*(i*(1.0/n_points)-0.5))/(2*tan(dx/2)));
                } 

            else {
                    u[i]=i*(1.0/n_points)*(1+2*(B-1)*(i*(1.0/n_points)-0.5)*(1-i*(1.0/n_points)));
            }

                sn[i]=u[i]/(A+(1.0-A)*u[i]);

            std::cout << "sn(i): " << sn[i] << std::endl;
            std::cout << "p_org[n_points]: " << &p_org[n_points-1] << std::endl;

            if(status==0){
                //p_new[i]=p_org[0]+(total_length*sn[i]); 
                std::cout << "FLAP maths.h" << std::endl;
            }

            //Here is the problem no. 2


            else if(status==1){
            //p_new[i]=p_org[0]-(total_length*sn[i]);
            std::cout << "SLAT maths.h" << std::endl;
            }
            //std::cout << "p_new in math: " << p_new << std::endl;


        }


}
```

My problem is, that I am unable to access the value of p_org or p_new. At the beginning I would like to give out the value of p_org and p_new. If I try it with a *, the compiler is complaining: error: no operator "<<" matches these operands
            operand types are: std::basic_ostream> << std::vector>
            std::cout << "Control at the beginning: p_org: " << (*p_org) << " p_new: " << (*p_new) << " n_points: " << n_points << " s_begin: " << s_begin << " s_end: " << s_end << " total_length: " << total_length << std::endl;

If I leave the * off, I get the addresses of p_org and p_new.

At the end of the code I would like to write the new value to p_new. If I use * to access the value, the compiler is complaining, if I leave it off, its complaining too with the following message:

```
error: no operator "-" matches these operands
        operand types are: std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>> - double
            p_new[i]=p_org[0]-(total_length*sn[i]);
                             ^
```

I tried to understand both problems, but until now I had no success. 
Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Do **not** pass `std::vector` by pointer.

Comment: Why are you burdening us with all that code? Surely you can cut this down to a few lines that display the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue with the compiler error can be cut down to a very simple program.

```
#include <vector>
void foo(std::vector<int>* pV)
{
    pV[0] = 10;  // error.
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> v(10);  
   foo(&v);
}
```

The issue is that `operator[]` as done above works for objects and references, not pointers.  Since `pv` is a pointer, you must dereference it first to obtain the object, and then apply `[]` to the dereferenced pointer.

```
void foo(std::vector<int>* pV)
{
    (*pV)[0] = 10;  // No error
}
```

The other form of calling `operator[]` can be also used, but is a bit more verbose:

```
void foo(std::vector<int>* pV)
{
    pv->operator[](0) = 10;  // No error
}
```

However, to alleviate having to do this, pass the vector by reference.  Then the "normal" way of using `operator[]` can be used.

```
#include <vector>
void foo(std::vector<int>& pV)
{
    pV[0] = 10;  // No error.
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> v(10);  
   foo(v);
}
```